# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python

```
import random

def football(length, width):
    return length * width

width = random.randrange
length = random.randrange
print random.randrange(200)
if (width, length <= 50):
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

Comment: `rand.randrange` needs a parameter.  The problem is that `(widh, length <= 50)` doesn't do what you think.  You need `if width <= 50 and length <= 50:`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (width , length <= 50):
```

This is asking whether the tuple `width,length` is less than or equal to the integer `50`. That's a nonsense question, since numbers cannot be meaningfully compared to tuples in Python.

If you mean to say "is either of the width or length less than 50", then use `or`

```
if width <= 50 or length <= 50:
```

If you meant "are both of the width and length less than 50", then use `and`

```
if width <= 50 and length <= 50:
```

As mentioned in the comments, you'll also need to call `random.randrange` with arguments, not just reference the function

```
width = random.randrange(start, stop)
```

and the same for `length`.